# Customer email be delivered to deleted item folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

One of user open a malicious email that caused their account to get blocked. We were able to unlock the user but now all new message are being redirected to the user deleted item folder.the problem does not appear to be in outlook as we have checked all rules etc. We have also closed outlook and problem still happen in owa.

Comment: Did the Email Supplier mark it all as SPAM?    Ask them about this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 0):

Have you configure any rules for the account? Inbox rules or transport rules?

As I know, when you select Ignore on an e-mail message, Outlook deletes that e-mail message and also keeps track of all future e-mail messages that are related to the ignored message. Please check if the messages are ignored by the status of the Ignore control on the ribbon.

[image]

For more information, please refer to: [Messages in an e-mail thread are automatically moved to the Deleted Items folder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/messages-in-an-e-mail-thread-are-automatically-moved-to-the-deleted-items-folder-7681a141-0b24-02ad-daac-32312bfcffd0).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.